# Cannot bind DependcyProperty of Model from collection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

In WPF project I use MVVM pattern.
I try to bind an item in a collection to `UserControl` but everything gets default value of `DependcyProperty`.

The Window xaml:

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Sessions}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Name="DebugTextBlock" Background="Bisque"
                      Text="{Binding Connection}"/>
                   <usercontrol:SessionsControl Model="{Binding Converter=
                     {StaticResource DebugConverter}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Where Sessions is

```
 private ObservableCollection<SessionModel> _sessions;

        public ObservableCollection<SessionModel> Sessions
        {
            get { return _sessions; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _sessions)) return;
                _sessions = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Sessions");
            }
        }
```

The SessionModel:

```
public class SessionModel:ViewModelBase
{
     private string _connection;

     public string  Connection
     {
            get { return _connection; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _connection) return;
                _connection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Connection");
            }
     }
}
```

In the `SessionsControl` I create `DependencyProperty`:

```
 //Dependency Property
 public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(SessionModel),
      typeof(SessionsControl), new PropertyMetadata(new SessionModel("default_from_control")));

 // .NET Property wrapper
 public SessionModel Model
 {
     get { return (SessionModel)GetValue(ModelProperty); }
     set { if (value != null) SetValue(ModelProperty, value); }
 }
```

and use this xaml to display connection in form:

```
<TextBlock Name="DebugControlTextBlock" Background="Gray" Text="{Binding Connection}"/>
```

So, when I run application

```
var windowModel = new WindowsModel();
var window = new SessionWindow(windowModel);
window.ShowDialog();
```

I always get `default_from_control` value in `DebugControlTextBlock`, but in `DebugTextBlock` get `the_real_connection`
[image: the window]

Even if I set breakpoint in `DebugConverter` I see that value is `default`.
The `DebugConverter` is simply wrapper to check correct binding:

```
 public class DebugConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("DebugConverter: " + (value!=null?value.ToString():"null"));
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

See solution on [github](https://github.com/Dr-klo/WPFCollectionBinding).
So, what happend when I Binding model to DependcyProperty?

Comment: We'd have to have a look at what your DebugConverter looks like to help here. If you're seeing the binding work for the string Connection property, then you're doing your binding correctly.

Also, you don't need to make your Sessions a dependency property. The ObservableCollection doesn't need to work in the way that other properties do when you work with MVVM. ObservableCollection will raise it's own notification to the UI when the collection changes. Your binding in this case would only be if you're listening for the entire collection being changed.

Comment: I add definition of `DebugConverter`. I know that `Sessions` list is so fat to notifications : the `WindowsModel` will used later.

Comment: It looks like you're just returning the same thing. Is your debug WriteLine working fine? This may be an issue with how you're using the Model once its bound in the control.

Comment: in `DebugConverter`, in textBlock and on window i always get default value.

Comment: I believe `CreoSessionModel` is a derived class of `SessionModel`?

Comment: Another quick suggestion - why do you need to have `Dependency property`? If your intention to show data only the you can set the `DataContext` directly of `UserControl` so that all child control inherit the same datacontext to resolve the bind property.

Comment: Sorry,I renamed variables and missed one.
quick-suggestion is alternative way. why my solution is not work?

Comment: Try this: `<usercontrol:SessionsControl Model="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=Model, Converter=
                     {StaticResource DebugConverter}}"/>` and see if this works. HTH

Comment: I push solution on [github](https://github.com/Dr-klo/WPFCollectionBinding)

Comment: @XAMlMAX - don't work

Comment: A little bit more info would be useful. What can you see in the Output Window?

Comment: @XAMlMAX the same `default_value`

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Output Window like Error:40 ?

Comment: @XAMlMAX there are no errors.  but i set `AncestorType=Window` because UserControl  is declared in  `Window.xaml`

Comment: If you didn't set the `UserControl's` `DataContext` this shouldn't make any difference. How is the progress anyway?

Comment: Just a thought, in your SessionControl.xaml.cs after InitialiseComponents(); put `this.DataContext = this;`. See if that works.

Comment: @XAMlMAX, I still get `default` value

Comment: OK, What if you don't set the `Binding` to your Model at all and leave your `UserControl` to inherit the DataContext from the `ListViewItem`?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try to make you Sessions property a DependencyProperty too. Otherwise you might have to manually Raise PropertyChanged for Sessions property.

Comment: at first I initialize collection of `Sessions` before initialise `Window`,
at second I already Raise PropertyChanged for `Sessions` (see already corrected topic).